# How to manage special cases?

Tags: python

I have some function that needs to return a non-negative integer after doing some calculation. However, there is some special cases where this calculation is not possible. I decided to "flag" them with different negative integers (**as I need to distinguish between those special cases later**). I am wondering if this is a bad practice. Intuitively, if I want to use the result returned by this function in another function, I can do some mistakes with those negative values. What do you think? Is there a better way to do it?

```py
def some_function(...)->int:

    if A:
        # do some calculation

        if B: 
            # do some calculation
            return meaningful_result
        
        else:
            try:
                # do some calculation

                if C:
                    # do some calculation
                    return meaningful_result
                else:
                    return -1 # -1 is somehow used to "flag" a first special case 
            
            except LookupError:
                return -2 # -2 is somehow used to "flag" a second special case 
    else: 
        return -3 # -3 is somehow used to "flag" a third special case
```

Comment: Can you add more context to this. If it is a special case, what do you want the function to do?

Comment: I will later do other calculation in another function depending on the special case. However those calculation does not use -1, -2 and -3, I just need to distinguish. If the returned valued is -3, I know that I am in some special case and do some calculation. The value -3 has no rule other than helping to identify the special case.

Comment: would the value that you computed help in the other calculation?

Comment: only if it's not a special case.

Comment: ok then I would use the flag and check in the upper functions

Comment: what do you mean by checking in the upper function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218486/discussion-between-gnahum-and-joffrey-l).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What do you think? Is there a better way to do it?

If you had only one special case I would say to return `None`. But in this case since you need to distinguish them it's better to give something more meaningful, like a descriptive string, than some arbitrary magical number. And you can update the return type hint to be `Union[str, int]`.

ps: you will need `from typing import Union` in this case